# snappydata job cancelled due to low memory

Tags: apache-spark, snappydata

I'm getting an *XCL54.T Query/DML/DDL '{0}' canceled due to low memory on member '{1}'. Try reducing the search space by adding more filter conditions to the where clause. query* error when creating a dataframe in Zeppelin by joining a tempview dataframe with a partitioned, column based snappydata table.

[This link](https://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/troubleshooting/troubleshooting_error_messages/#query-dml-dll) recommends configuring tables to evict rows as a troubleshooting measure for this error message, but it says [here](https://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/reference/sql_reference/create-table/) that *The tables are evicted to disk by default, which means table data overflows to a local SnappyStore disk store.* so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I'm using the community edition, is this perhaps due to the off heap management exclusive to the 'paid for' version?

Any suggestions as to how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

It might be your spark operation that is consuming a lot of the memory too. What were you executing that triggered this exception?